# How to get image from Rss?

Tags: android

i would like to get image from the rss news and present it above my text description..is that possible?

the image is like that in the rss xml:

```
<media:thumbnail xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" url="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Dh8DqJBv3kg/TeoOh-MnCiI/AAAAAAAAU90/-oHd6LUSwqE/s72-c/1.jpg" height="72" width="72" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you currently parsing the rest of the RSS feed? If so, did you create your own custom parser to read it or are you using an existing RSS parser library?

There is a walkthrough of how to create your own custom parser [here  (including source code for a simple android app using it)](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/08/android-rss-reader-tutorial.html)   if you use a custom approach then it is very easy to amend the XML parser to read any additional information you want based on the required tags.